# Accessing an array in an object

Tags: php, arrays, object

If i knew the correct terms to search these would be easy to google this but im not sure on the terminology.

I have an API that returns a big object. There is one particular one i access via:

```
$bug->fields->customfield_10205[0]->name;
//result is johndoe@gmail.com
```

There is numerous values and i can access them by changing it from 0 to 1 and so on

But i want to loop through the array (maybe thats not the correct term) and get all the emails in there and add it to a string like this:

```
implode(',', $array);
//This is private code so not worried too much about escaping
```

Would have thought i just do something like:
    echo implode(',', $bug->fields->customfield_10205->name);

Also tried
    echo implode(',', $bug->fields->customfield_10205);

And
    echo implode(',', $bug->fields->customfield_10205[]->name);

The output im looking for is:
    'johndoe@gmail.com,marydoe@gmail.com,patdoe@gmail.com'

Where am i going wrong and i apologize in advance for the silly question, this is probably so newbie

Comment: Is this a SimpleXML object? Is it possible to perhaps `var_dump()` the value of `$bug->fields->customfield_10205`?

Comment: And what output do you get instead? If this is SimpleXML, these are not *really* arrays, so you can access them with `[]` and `foreach` but not use array functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an iteration, such as

```
# an array to store all the name attribute
$names = array();

foreach ($bug->fields->customfield_10205 as $idx=>$obj)
{
  $names[] = $obj->name;
}

# then format it to whatever format your like
$str_names = implode(',', $names);
```

PS: You should look for attribute email instead of name, however, I just follow your code

Answer (score 0):

use this code ,and loop through the array.

```
$arr = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($bug->fields->customfield_10205); $i++)
{
    $arr[] = $bug->fields->customfield_10205[$i]->name;
}
$arr = implode(','$arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in PHP without using an additional loop and a temporary list:

```
$names = array();
foreach($bug->fields->customfield_10205 as $v)
{
    $names[] = $v->name;
}
implode(',', $names);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map` function like this

```
function map($item)
{
    return $item->fields->customfield_10205[0]->name;
}

implode(',', array_map("map", $bugs)); // the $bugs is the original array
```